# Can I use something other than id with link_to in my rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, link-to

The *rails way* of making links in your view is to use `link_to`.  Passing it an object will link to that object's `id`.  How can I use my object's `match_id` instead of `id` with `link_to`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the `to_param` method in your model to return the value of `match_id` to have `link_to` and other rails helpers automatically use that value when generating urls.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using `link_to(@object)` I don't believe you can specify something other than the default object id. However, if you use the actual path helper for the route you want, you can specify the id with `object_path(@object.match_id)`